# Manchu and Mongolian script

Tags: xetex, cjk, linguistics, arabic

I am trying to write a document including Manchu script on a Mac. Manchu is written with the Mongolian alphabet with the addition of some diacritics, but the extra diacritics are included in standard Mongolian fonts included in Mac OS. Manchu/Mongolian script functions similar to Arabic script, in that the letters are connected and their shape varies depending on their position within a word.

However, Mac OS is unable to input or even display Manchu/Mongolian properly, because it cannot handle the different forms that letters should take depending on their position within the word (isolated, initial, medial, or final).

PCs can now both input and display Manchu/Mongolian.

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to enter Manchu/Mongolian in LaTeX (say, by typing the UNICODE numbers of the letters), and have the typesetter produce proper script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in general you can use the Unicode numbers or the corresponding letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{圈点满文印刷体}% the font name of manchu.ttf}
\begin{document}

abcdefghijklmnopqrst

\char055\char056\char057 

\end{document}
```

[image]

You hvae to use platex, lualatex or omega to write it in the correct direction from top to bottom.

Comment: You can “hack” Mongolian top to buttom, left to right direction in XeTeX by using a combination of `Vertical=RotatedGlyphs` font feature, `\XeTeXupwardsmode` and box rotation with `graphicx`

Comment: Using `platex` makes more sense

Comment: Of course, but I don’t know how complete are pTeX’s OpenType layout capabilities (if there are any).

Comment: sorry, I meant `uplatex` the unicode variant which can handle otf fonts

Comment: @Herbert Thanks! But when I use your minimal example, I get an error message and there is no output. FontBook in Mac told me there might be an issue with the CJK name of the font, but I've tried to load it using both the PostScript name and the path + filename as well, still with no luck. Do you know what might be the problem? I have the fontspec package installed and I'm using it successfully elsewhere.

Comment: I had to rename the font, as Mac OS could not read the CJK name (I used TTX), but now it works! However, I realized that Manchu cannot simply be written using Möllendorf/Norman transcription, but must be sort of transliterated from the Manchu script according to this table: http://luodewei55.blog.sohu.com/110042728.html . That being said, it works. Thanks!

Comment: @KhaledHosny Could you please give me a minimal example with rotated text?

Comment: @Mårten: sorry, I don’t have a first hand experience with this, but I think web searching for XeTeX and Mongolian might give some hits.

Answer (score 8):

> The below functionality is available as the [`manchuxetex` package](https://github.com/pcdi/manchuxetex/blob/master/manchuxetex.pdf) on GitHub.

A minimal example as to demonstrate [Khaled Hosny](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/729/khaled-hosny)’s point of hacking Manchu/Mongolian into top-to-bottom, left-to-right:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\dcw}[]{DaicingWhite}%
\begin{document}
\noindent
Line above\\% to demonstrate that the lines are being stacked as normal
\rotatebox{-90}{%
\XeTeXupwardsmode1\\% successive lines will be stacked upwards instead of downwards
\begin{minipage}{4em}% this will be the vertical length of the Mongolian section
{\dcw% Font: Daicing White
1 ᠮᠠᠨᠵᡠ ᡤᡳᠰᡠᠨ\\% direct Unicode input of Manchu letters
2 ᠮᠠᠨᠵᡠ ᡤᡳᠰᡠᠨ
}% End font
\end{minipage}
\XeTeXupwardsmode0
}% End rotatebox

\noindent
Line underneath
\end{document}
```

This yields the following:

[image: Manchu text between sections of English text]

Daicing White’s letters are already rotated, therefore there is no need to use the `Vertical=RotatedGlyphs` font feature here.

Answer (score 0):

A preliminary solution for Lua(La)TeX could be made emulating XeTeX upwards mode via inverting text lines and then rotating the result. The only issue is the paragraph break I couldn't get rid of. Text extract from http://www.cjvlang.com/Writing/writmongol/tradmononsite.html for comparison. Mongolian White is available from here: http://www.mongolfont.com/en/font/mnglwhiteotf.html

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Mongolian White}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Mongolian]
\begin{luacode*}
userdata = userdata or {}
--Idea taken from chickenize's \boustrophedon
userdata.mongolian = function(head)
    rot = node.new(node.id("whatsit"),node.subtype("pdf_literal"))
    rot2 = node.new(node.id("whatsit"),node.subtype("pdf_literal"))
    for line in node.traverse_id(0,head) do
        w = line.width/65536*0.99625 
        rot.data = "-1 0 0 -1 "..w.." 0 cm"
        rot2.data = "-1 0 0 -1 "..-w.." 0 cm"
        line.head = node.insert_before(line.head,line.head,node.copy(rot))
    
    node.insert_after(line.head,node.tail(line.head),node.copy(rot2))
    end
    return head
end
\end{luacode*}
\def\startmongolian{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter", userdata.mongolian, "mongolian")}}

\def\stopmongolian{%
%Don't remove \par !
\par\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback("post_linebreak_filter", "mongolian")}%
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox{90}{%
\parbox{8cm}{%
\startmongolian
\begin{flushleft}
    ᠣᠢᠷ᠎ᠠ ᠵᠢᠨ ᠡᠳᠦᠷ᠂ ᠦᠪᠦᠷ ᠮᠣᠩᠭᠣᠯ ᠦᠨ ᠰᠢᠯᠢ ᠵᠢᠨ ᠭᠣᠣᠯ ᠠᠢᠮᠠᠭ ᠦᠨ ᠰᠢᠯᠣᠭᠣᠨ ᠬᠦᠬᠡ ᠬᠣᠰᠢᠭᠣᠨ ᠦ ᠰᠢᠭᠦᠬᠦ ᠬᠣᠷᠢᠶ᠎ᠠ ᠨᠢᠭᠡᠨ ᠬᠦᠴᠦᠷᠬᠡᠭᠯᠡᠨ ᠨᠦᠵᠢᠳᠯᠡᠭᠰᠡᠨ ᠶᠠᠯᠠᠲᠣ ᠬᠡᠷᠡᠭ ᠲᠦ ᠰᠢᠭᠦᠯᠲᠡ ᠬᠢᠪᠡ᠃ ᠰᠢᠭᠦᠨ ᠲᠠᠰᠣᠯᠣᠯᠳᠠ ᠪᠠᠷ᠂ ᠵᠠᠭᠠᠯᠳᠣᠭᠳᠠᠭᠴᠢ ᠡᠷᠬᠢᠮᠲᠦ ᠵᠢ ᠬᠦᠴᠦᠷᠭᠡᠭᠯᠡᠨ᠂ ᠨᠦᠵᠢᠳᠯᠡᠭᠰᠡᠨ ᠶᠡᠯ᠎ᠡ ᠪᠡᠷ ᠭᠣᠷᠪᠠᠨ ᠵᠢᠯ ᠦᠨ ᠬᠣᠭᠣᠴᠠᠭ᠎ᠠ ᠲᠠᠢ ᠬᠣᠷᠢᠬᠣ ᠡᠷᠡᠭᠦᠦ ᠪᠡᠷ ᠰᠢᠳᠬᠡᠭᠰᠡᠨ ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ᠃
\end{flushleft}
\stopmongolian
}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]