# Meaning of LTL direction

Tags: luatex

@DavidCarlisle explains [in an answer to a previous question about luatex direction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351558/7712) that in LTL, the last L means that "the top of the glyphs within the line is [...] L(left)."

But I don't understand what does it means to have the top of the glyphs within the line at left!

Maybe a graphics could help me?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand the three items (= letters) in TLT, TRT, RTT and LTL respectively, the first item denotes the side of a parbox (or any other thought box which contains the text) where the first line is typeset. For English and Arabic, this would be top, since the first line would be typeset along the top of the box. Vertically typeset Japanese would start at the right side of this box, traditional Mongolian at the left side.

The second item regards one single line of the paragrah. If we again think of this whole line as one box, English text would obviously start at the left side of this box. Arabic would start at the right side and both Japanese and Mongolian would start at the top.

Now, the third item regards one single glyph within this line. Again we think of one line of text as a row (or column) of boxes put together. Each of these boxes has a distinct orientation. As in English and Arabic the glyphs are not rotated, the top of the letters is indeed at the top of the boxes. The same holds true for Japanese. But Mongolian glyphs are typically rotated to the right, so that the left side of each glyph is at the top of such a box.

The reason why Mongolian fonts are designed horizontally is because the letters are joined together like in Arabic. If the text rendering software does not support vertical text, the glyphs are still properly connected this way and the reader just have to turn the page in order to be able to read a word (but not a whole text as the lines are then wrongly ordered).

I hope my explanations are right.

---

*Just for clarification: The letters “Abc” in the picture below are only meant to make clear the direction of the text and the orientation of the glyphs. Of course, one would not write English words backwards in an Arabic text and the glyphs of longer English words would of course be rotated if they appear in an Japanese text.*

[image]

Comment: Maybe I did not get it right. I just tried myself with LuaTeX, but the result with LTL and fonts with horizontally designed Mongolian glyphs would not work. Rather the glyphs are not rotated at all. The result is very similar to the RTT orientation … So, does someone else know more?

Comment: I get the same. The glyphs aren't joined, and out by 90 degrees (clockwise).

Just a guess: I suspect the glyphs are rotated first (which is OK for Japanese and Chinese), which operation then prevents contextual joining of the glyphs inside the word boxes, so they appear as isolate forms. Then the line is rotated into vertical position (OK for CJK).

Moreover, the lines aren't stacking, and later paragraphs could be printing off-page.

Answer (score 2):

Given the apparent page-shipping out tweaking that looks to be required for LTL, and without a suitable hack cropping up, as interim alternatives in the meantime for Mongolian/Manju users there are:

(A)

MonTex (`usepackage{mls}`) from 2002, which can do Uighur and Manju script, as well as Cyrillic, using a transliteration method, ranging from words to paragraphs to pages to documents.

[image: montex]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mls}

\begin{document}
\section{MonTex}
{\mnr  mongol x"al ba \rnm english text with a {\mnr  mongol}           word inserted}
\vskip2em
\mabox{3.75cm}{%
\noindent\raggedleft han-i           araha           sunjahacin-i           hergen           kamcihamanju           gisun-i           bulekubithe.           abkai           so\v{s}ohon.emu           hacin.           nadan           meyen.%
}
\end{document}
```

(B)

Another method is with plain Unicode input in xelatex and the use of `XeTeXupwardsmode1` (which stacks the lines upwards) combined with rotated minipages, so the end result is LTL.

[image: LTL by hand]

(example font here is Noto Sans Mongolian; 
and if you have a font with glyphs already rotated, you won't need the fontspec option `Vertical=RotatedGlyphs`)

For an MWE, see the answer here
[Manchu and Mongolian script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87259/manchu-and-mongolian-script)

=========

At a guess: for the answer:

The second "L" in LTL may refer to how the font glyphs are stored in the font file, leftways. Printing vertically on a computer was rare: a hack was to print sideways and then physically turn (rotate) the page. Printing English vertically in Japanese, but to be read sideways, is a similar idea.

From the reader's point of view, the third code is always "T".

No-one writes bottom-up, so that reduces the symmetry group by half.

Starting at the top, the sentence begins at either right or left (no-one starts in the middle, either), and from that starting position it can go in one of two directions, across or down. = 4 combinations.

English and Spanish start at top left and choose to make the sentence go across = to the right. When the line is full, the next line is underneath.

TLT
[image: TLT]

Hebrew and Arabic start at top right and choose to make the sentence go across = to the left. When the line is full, the next line is underneath.

TRT
[image: TRT]

Japanese and traditional Chinese start at top right and choose to make the sentence go vertically = downwards. When the (vertical) line is full, the next line is to the left.

RTT
[image: RTT]

[image: RTT example]

Mongolian and Manchu start at top left and choose to make the sentence go vertically = downwards. When the (vertical) line is full, the next line is to the right.

LT"L"
[image: LTL]

Scanning characters in a text does not govern storage of glyphs in a font file, except by coincidence. So that might be the reason.

Imagine different circumstances in computer history: starting with writing from bottom-up, when the line is full continue it on the other side of the paper/tree/clay (flip vertically or horizontally) and read it from a reflection in the water while upside-down in said tree! How would the programmers write the code? :)