# How to display traditional Mongolian in a Latex environment correctly

Tags: xetex, languages, vertical

I want to display traditional Mongolian in a Latex environment.Traditional Mongolian text displays text from top to bottom, left to right, and can be encoded in Unicode.The key is to mix English, Chinese, and Mongolian.I hope someone can help me make it happen. Such as web page displays the traditional Mongolian http://mongol.people.com.cn/15784620.html

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The webpage link you provided seems to contain a lot of propaganda and other material that is wholly unrelated to typesetting traditional Mongolian script in LaTeX. For instance, the cookie blocker of my web browser reported rejecting more than two dozen requests for tracking cookies in just the first few seconds after I clicked on the page link you provided. Please provide a link to a non-propaganda page.

Comment: Is Mongolian anything like Pecha?

Comment: If you’re looking for some innocuous text samples from a language, [the Unicode Consortium claims that this is from the UN Universal Declaration of Human Rights](https://www.unicode.org/udhr/d/udhr_khk_mong.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, `fontspec` does not support vertical typesetting. The `mongolian` language file for Babel uses the Cyrillic alphabet. There is an older package, MonTeX, that allows traditional vertical typesetting, although it uses obsolete 8-bit encodings.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend http://www.cjvlang.com/mongol/silkroad.html (for a non-propaganda page, that is, not for a solution).

With David Carlisle's kind assistance, I could typeset Mongolian top-to-bottom, left-to-right using plain XeTeX, but had no idea how one might do the same in a XeLaTeX environment until I read [a 2013 contribution by Brian Ammon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87259/manchu-and-mongolian-script/140972#140972).  I include a modified version of Brian's original code below.

```
% !TeX Program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass {minimal}
\usepackage {fontspec}
\newfontfamily \MongolianWhite [] {Mongolian White}
\parindent = 0 em
\parskip = \baselineskip

\begin{document}
Text above

\rotatebox {-90}
    {%
        \XeTeXupwardsmode = 1
        \begin {minipage} {0,7 \vsize}
            {\MongolianWhite \parindent = 1 em
                 \noindent [1] ᠨᠡᠢᠭᠡᠮ ᠵᠢᠷᠤᠮ ᠦᠨ ᠭᠣᠣᠯᠯᠠᠭᠴᠢ ᠥᠷᠳᠡᠭ ᠦᠨ ᠦᠵᠡᠯᠲᠡ ᠵᠢᠨ ᠬᠡᠦᠬᠡᠳ ᠦᠨ ᠵᠢᠷᠣᠭᠲᠤ ᠤᠩᠰᠢᠭᠤ

                [2] ᠪᠢᠴᠢᠬᠠᠨ ᠨᠠᠢᠵᠠ ᠮᠢᠨᠢ᠂ ᠲᠠ ᠨᠠᠷ ᠬᠠᠪᠤᠷ ᠦᠨ ᠬᠦᠷᠢ ᠵᠢᠨ ᠰᠢᠷᠭᠡᠭ ᠪᠥᠭᠡᠯᠵᠢᠬᠦ ᠵᠢ ᠬᠠᠷᠠᠭᠰᠠᠨ ᠤᠤ? ᠵᠢᠵᠢᠭᠬᠡᠨ ᠬᠦᠷᠢ ᠬᠣᠷᠣᠬᠠᠢ ᠵᠢᠨ ᠪᠥᠭᠡᠯᠵᠢᠭᠰᠡᠨ ᠰᠢᠷᠬᠡᠭ ᠵᠢᠡᠷ ᠳᠣᠷᠭ᠎ᠠ ᠨᠡᠭᠡᠭᠡᠳ ᠭᠣᠶᠣ ᠰᠠᠢᠬᠠᠨ ᠬᠤᠪᠴᠠᠰᠤ ᠬᠢᠵᠦ ᠪᠣᠯᠳᠠᠭ᠃ ᠲᠤᠩ ᠣᠯᠠᠨ ᠭᠠᠳᠠᠭᠠᠳᠤ ᠵᠢᠨ ᠬᠦᠮᠦᠨ ᠮᠠᠨ ᠦ ᠤᠯᠤᠰ ᠦᠨ ᠲᠣᠷᠭ᠎ᠠ ᠲᠣᠷᠳᠣᠩ ᠢ ᠮᠠᠰᠢ ᠪᠠᠬᠠᠷᠠᠭᠳᠠᠭ ᠰᠢᠦ᠃

                [3] ᠠᠵᠢᠯᠴᠢ ᠬᠥᠳᠡᠯᠮᠥᠷᠢᠴᠢ ᠲᠤᠮᠳᠠᠳᠤ ᠵᠢᠨ ᠬᠦᠮᠦᠨ ᠵᠦᠢᠯ ᠵᠦᠢᠯ ᠦᠨ ᠬᠦᠴᠢᠷ ᠪᠡᠷᠬᠡ ᠵᠢ ᠲᠤᠭᠤᠯᠵᠤ ᠳᠤᠷᠳᠤᠩ ᠢ ᠧᠦ᠋ᠷᠣᠫᠡ ᠲᠢᠪ ᠦᠨ ᠭᠠᠵᠠᠷ ᠦᠨ ᠳᠤᠮᠳᠠᠳᠤ ᠲᠡᠩᠭᠢᠰ ᠦᠨ ᠡᠷᠭᠢ ᠬᠥᠪᠡᠭᠡᠨ ᠦ ᠣᠯᠣᠰ ᠤᠳ ᠲᠤ ᠬᠦᠷᠲᠡᠯ᠎ᠡ ᠵᠥᠭᠡᠭᠡᠪᠦᠷᠢᠯᠡᠬᠦ ᠵᠠᠮ ᠢ ᠨᠡᠭᠡᠭᠡᠭᠰᠡᠨ ᠶᠤᠮ ᠰᠢᠦ᠃ ᠲᠡᠷᠡ ᠨᠢ ᠡᠷᠲᠡᠨ ᠦ ᠴᠠᠩ ᠠᠨ (ᠣᠳᠣ ᠵᠢᠨ ᠰᠢ ᠠᠨ) ᠡᠴᠡ ᠡᠬᠢᠯᠡᠵᠤ᠂ ᠬᠠᠮᠤᠭ ᠬᠣᠯᠠ ᠳᠦ ᠪᠡᠨ ᠢᠲ᠋ᠠᠯᠢ ᠵᠢᠨ ᠷᠣᠮᠠ ᠬᠦᠷᠳᠡᠭ ᠪᠠᠢᠭᠰᠠᠨ ᠪᠢᠯᠡ᠃
            }
        \end{minipage}
        % \XeTeXupwardsmode = 0 not required — \rotatebox provides grouping.
    }

Text below
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Although I concur that `article` is not required, it does not harm either. `minimal` on the other hand is often _too_ minimal, and it's better not to "teach" people to use it (unless there is a good reason to), so I'd appreciate if you could keep `article`. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Phelype.  My goal is not to teach people "best practice" for LaTeX (a task for which I am probably the least qualified person in the world), but rather to give them the necessary and sufficient tools to typeset vertical Mongolian.  From that perspective, \documentclass {minimal} is (IMHO) the  best choice — using another class such as "article" (or "scrartcl", cf. Brian Ammon) might suggest that that particular document class is required.  Thus I prefer to provide the simplest possible example and leave others to expand on it if they incorporate it in their own work

Comment: The thing about this site is that the "learning" oftentimes comes from copy-pasting, so in the same way that using `article` may give the wrong impression that it's required (although I don't think that's the case), using `minimal` will probably do the same. But no problem, your answer, your rules. I just wanted to make clear (mostly for future readers) that `minimal` has very limited use-cases. Also, it's completely fine to post examples in plain if you prefer to do so; there's no restriction about that in the site :-)

Comment: OK, just to add that I was genuinely misled by Brian Ammon's use of "scrartcl" and thought it must be necessary, so when I found that it was not I amended the code so as to reduce the risk of others falling into the same trap ...